# Finding the value of the function $f$ from $|f(x)-f(y)| \le 7{|x-y|}^{201}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

> $f$ is a continuous function from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$ such that for any two real numbers $x$ and $y$
> $$|f(x)-f(y)| \le 7{|x-y|}^{201} \text.$$
> Then will this function be constant?

###### My attempt:

I divide both sides by $|x-y|$ and then take limit as $x$ goes to $y$ on both sides which will give the derivative as $0$ which means the function will be constant, but I am not sure if this is the correct answer or not, I am getting confused because of the seven and the power. If my approach is correct, is there a general form for which this kind of equation will always give a constant function?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your approach is correct. More generally, if $a,b>0$ and$$(\forall x,y\in\mathbb{R}):\bigl\lvert f(x)-f(y)\bigr\rvert\leqslant a\lvert x-y\rvert^{b+1},$$then $f$ is constant. That's so because$$x\neq y\implies\left\lvert\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}\right\rvert\leqslant a\lvert x-y\rvert^b$$and therefore $f'(x)=0$ for each real $x$

Comment: In the second to last step, we have to take the limit as well , right?

Comment: Yes, of course.